# How to Simulate stress test reports generated from on a server based on another server config?

Tags: testing, jmeter, stress-testing, stress

I did some stress tests on a stage server and got some reports and thresholds and now I want to know what will be the numbers on the production server?

Is there any solutions to simulate the results on the production server based on another server config?

Answer (score 0):

If stage server differs from production - you won't be able to extrapolate the results and calculate the anticipated metrics based on results from the different server.

In this case you can utilize your existing test results from [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) or [soak testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/soak-testing-and-spike-testing) perspective as the bottleneck might be connected with a 3rd-party component like database which can be tested separately using [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)

But you **cannot** state that i.e. if stage server has `A` GB of RAM and you were able to reach `B` requests per second then prod server which has `A*2` GB of RAM will give you `B*2` requests per second.